# Instance count of all compartments in OCI

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Can we get the total sum of instances of all compartments in oracle cloud Infrastructure?

I'm able to get the sum of all instance for the given compartment using the comand line, `oci compute instance list-vnics --compartment-id $compartment_id`  . But how to get the total count of all instances across all compartment?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get the instance details from all compartments of every region in OCI.

```
import oci
from oci.config import from_file
from oci.signer import Signer

configAPI = from_file()  # Config file is read from user's home location i.e., ~/.oci/config
auth = Signer(
    tenancy=configAPI['tenancy'],
    user=configAPI['user'],
    fingerprint=configAPI['fingerprint'],
    private_key_file_location=configAPI['key_file'],
    pass_phrase=configAPI['pass_phrase']
)
COMPARTMENT_ID="ocid1.tenancy.oc1..abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  # this should be root compartment OCID

identity_client = oci.identity.IdentityClient(configAPI)

list_compartments_response = identity_client.list_compartments(
    compartment_id=COMPARTMENT_ID,
    compartment_id_in_subtree=True)

# Get the list of compartments including child compartments except root compartment
compartmentlist = list_compartments_response.data

# Get the details of root compartment & append to the compartment list so that we have the full list of compartments in the given tenancy
root_compartment = identity_client.get_compartment(
    compartment_id=COMPARTMENT_ID).data
compartmentlist.append(root_compartment)


# Get the list of all OCI regions
list_regions_response = identity_client.list_regions()
region_obj = list_regions_response.data

instance_json = {"instances": []}

for region in region_obj:
    
    config = {
        "user": configAPI['user'],
        "key_file": configAPI['key_file'],
        "fingerprint": configAPI['fingerprint'],
        "tenancy": configAPI['tenancy'],
        "region": getattr(region, "name")
    }

    for data in compartmentlist:  # For each compartment
        compartmentocid = getattr(data, "id")
        core_client = oci.core.ComputeClient(config)

        list_instances_response = core_client.list_instances(compartment_id=compartmentocid)

        list_instances_obj = list_instances_response.data
        if list_instances_obj:
            instance_json["instances"].append(list_instances_obj)

print(instance_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires the [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) utility.

Iterate through all compartments to print all instance details to the console:

```
for f
  in $(oci iam compartment list --all | jq -rc '.data[] | ."id"');
do
  oci compute instance list --compartment-id $f;
done
```

If you want a count of all instances you can use:

```
# Load instance details into a variable.
x=$(for f in $(oci iam compartment list --all | jq -rc '.data[] | ."id"'); do oci compute instance list --compartment-id $f; done)

# Count instances.
echo $x | grep '"display-name"' | wc -l
```

Note this only counts instances in one region.